# I'm having trouble finding the goblin tinkerer

Tags: terraria-mobile

I'm looking for the goblin tinkerer and I HAVE beat a goblin army and done the things you need to do to get him. I have looked through every cave I can find and still no sign. Are there any potions or items that will help me find him? And how deep should I go?

Answer (score 4):

**The Goblin Tinkerer is not in a specific location. He will simply spawn near you at random, then respawn later if you miss him.**

The [Goblin Tinkerer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_tinkerer) can be found anywhere on the [Cavern layer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cavern) of your world after you've defeated a Goblin Army invasion. However, like all bound NPCs, he is not placed in a single specific spot in the world for you to find; rather, as you're moving around the relevant area, the game will randomly decide to spawn him somewhere near you, and you may stumble upon him.

You are not required to search inside the [Dungeon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dungeon). However, you may have better luck looking there (at the Cavern level) simply due to the abundance of easily-accessible open space in which the Goblin Tinkerer might spawn; the Dungeon does not inherently increase the chances of finding him. Items which might help you in locating him (and other bound NPCs) include the [Hunter Potion](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hunter_Potion) (which will highlight bound NPCs in addition to enemies) and the [Lifeform Analyzer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lifeform_Analyzer) (which will alert you if certain rare creatures, including bound NPCs, are nearby). Unfortunately, as of the writing of this answer, the Lifeform Analyzer is not yet available on Mobile, but the Hunter Potion is, and likely just as good (if consumable).

Answer (score -2):

[**Goblin tinkerer**](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin_Tinkerer) is a NPC that spawns in your world after defeating the goblin army. As you have done that you now need to find a [**dungeon**](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Dungeon).

The Goblin Tinkerer will need to be rescued by right-clicking on him. In the dungeon, he may be found above or below sea level, though he is usually in the rocky layer. The player can make a pathway below sea level and run across it to spawn the Goblin(as well as the Wizard, untested with Mechanic).

Comment: The dungeon is where the old man was, right? If so, I want to say that I have explored it already. (Skeletron being defeated with help from my cousins)

Comment: I have also looked under the living wood tree.

Comment: 'The player can make a pathway below sea level and run across it to spawn the Goblin.' So basically a bridge running straight across the world just under sea level.

Comment: Just found him hiding in a.... Dart trap? I broke it and he came out! And he was also poisoned.

Comment: Well that's odd... I'd say that was a glitch/bug and to be careful using the goblin in case something happens. Just saying.